# Internet speed stutters—even Ethernet connected devices—when Wi-Fi is enabled on a D-Link DSL-2750U ADSL Wi-Fi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

At my workplace, we have a [D-Link DSL-2750U ADSL Wi-Fi Router](http://www.dlink.co.in/products/?pid=452) which is connected to a [24-port D-Link Ethernet switch](http://www.dlink.co.in/products/?pid=118). It is a very small setup. About 20 clients connect to the network (including Laptops and Smartphones) via Wi-Fi and there is an Ethernet line just in case Wi-Fi goes down. Some clients also connect to Ethernet when not connected via Wi-Fi.

The ADSL router is connected to an external ADSL line from the service provider whose downstream rate is about 8 Mbps and upstream rate is 1 Mbps.

Recently, the network started having issues, when the Wi-Fi functionality of the router is turned on, the Internet speed becomes so slow that it becomes unusable (even on the Ethernet line) and the moment I turn off the Wi-Fi functionality of the router, the Internet speed goes back up on the Ethernet connection.

EDIT: I recently discovered that when I turn on WiFi on my iPhone, the whole network goes down. I got a new iPhone as well, but transferred all my settings from old iPhone. It doesn't happen for other iPhone users

I am no network expert. What could be the issue? If the issue is with the network setup, should I consider upgrading the router?

Comment: Change the WiFi key to something nobody knows and see if the problem still happens. If so, it's in the router itself. If not, it's some device that's using the WiFi.

Comment: It still happens. I tried every possibility I could do. Changed keys, disabled Wi-Fi. It has stopped for now since a day or two but it happened sometime back for many day, but not always.
I couldn't even find other device connected via Wi-Fi other than the usual devices.

Comment: Did you try restarting the router?

Comment: @DavidPostill That is the first thing to try. Restarted many times

Comment: I discovered recently that when I turn on WiFi on my iPhone, the whole network goes down. I got a new iPhone as well, but transferred all my settings from old iPhone. What could the issue be?

Comment: You don't have to use the WiFi that comes with this router if it's defective. You can connect another router and program it as an access point to handle the wifi part of your network. As a bonus, this allows you to position it in a more convenient location for better signal.

Comment: But all other devices connected to WiFi network work perfectly. Even other iOS devices. It's an issue with my iPhone, I guess

Comment: @AnujRajput It could be that your iPhone was trying to download an update. It happens to my Windows 10 machine all the time. (Unfortunately there isn't an option to disable it on Windows 10 without changing settings that break other stuff.)